# Three.js and WebGL

Tags: canvas, 3d, webgl, three.js

Please help me with this! I made this last night and upload it on a web server but it doesn't work. I use Three.js JavaScript library and WebGL http://threejs.hit.bg/Three.html

One more question - how to make WebglRenderer be faster and better than CanvasRenderer if it is possible.

Comment: Please, ask only 1 question at a time. Also, "it doesn't work" is very broad. Your question would be better if you posted an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/). That makes it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link does not work. WebglRenderer is allways faster than CanvasRenderer, but is not supported on all Browsers. See overview here: http://caniuse.com/webgl